# Unable to edit a previous answer

Tags: support

Getting redirected to

400 Bad request

Your browser sent an invalid request.

Whenever I try and post the answer...  Is this happening to others?

This is for: [Add article to transactional publication without generating new snapshot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12725/add-article-to-transactional-publication-without-generating-new-snapshot/162749#162749)

Comment: Seems to have got through when I posted it as a new answer....

Comment: Two things: it's a large answer and that may be part of it (will alert some SE devs) ... do you want me to try and do what it was you were trying to do or do you want to simply delete the old answer?

Comment: Thanks @jcolebrand, I'm happy for the old answer to be deleted, though I'll leave it up in case the se Devs find it useful.

Comment: Probably this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341457/malware-protection-gone-awry/341463#341463

Comment: Thanks @Shog9 !

Comment: Interesting, however posting the text as a new answer worked. (Identical markup), does editing an answer post the original and the new? (Could be it went over a size threshold?)